# Running kotlin tests with gradlew is throwing java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: android, testing, kotlin

Running test from the terminal with:

```
./gradlew testAppReleaseUnitTest --tests namespace.test.class
```

Throws a:

```
java.lang.SecurityException at Class.kt:42
```

Running the same test from android studio works fine.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the latest version of android gradle plugin.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65809932

Solution for now was to downgrade.